# C# BadImageFormatException when saving data using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline

Tags: c#, xna, visual-studio-2015, xna-4.0

First question on here and I am feeling pretty stumped, I've searched around but couldn't find something that I could apply to my situations, any help or direction to a prior question would be appreciated.

I'm receiving an error when trying to create some new files from my form. I'm following a guide  at XNA Game Programming Academy (xnagpa_net/xna4rpg_php), I'm up to step 14 but I believe this started happening earlier and I hadn't noticed it yet.

Screenshot of Error

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Please have a look at the above error and give me any tips.
My code for RpgEditor.FormMain.cs is [here](http://hastebin.com/qujowukapi.avrasm), it says something about line 128 which relates to;

```
if (Directory.Exists(gamePath))
    throw new Exception("Selected directory already exists.");
```

I'm not sure why though, because I'm creating a brand new folder/directory when I am attempting to save the data.

If it helps, the subdirectories are being created by the process but I recieve that error and no files inside.

edit: I've downloaded the example project on his site and it's working fine with that, so I don't believe it's an issue with my system configuration.. must be a project setting or line of code somewhere..

Comment: I've seen people commenting in other questions to set the platform to "Any CPU" but as we can see, I already have that set for my RpgEditor; http://puu.sh/ltbO5/58d60991db.png

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to change the configuration settings.

It was set to AnyCPU but I had to change to x86. 
The setting wasn't there originally, I had to create new and copy settings from AnyCPU.

Why this works I don't know, but it does :)